# Значение выражения "сочту за честь"

Tags: значение-слов

Объясните, пожалуйста, значение выражения "сочту за честь".

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, пожалуйста, отметьте его [как принятый](/help/accepted-answer) (галочка рядом с ответом) и поставьте ему значок ▲.

Answer (score 3):

Горд, что меня посчитали достойным что-либо сделать.

Answer (score 2):

*С радостью приму такое предложение* (присутствовать, принять участие, служить или работать там-то  или с кем-то, сделать что-то), *сознавая его как знак оказанного мне уважения*; мне приятно, что вы сочли меня *достойным* для того, что предлагаете (или для осуществления того, о чём просите).

Это может быть и в сослагательной форме, если говорящий "напрашивается" (сочту за честь, **если** вы доверите мне это дело и т. п.)

Answer (score 2):

**ЧЕСТЬ,** Почёт, уважение. Воздать, оказать ч. кому-л. (оказать уважение).

***Сочту/почту за честь*** ― буду считать, что вы оказали  мне честь (почет, уважение), посчитали **достойным** для чего-либо.

**Так говорили раньше:**

Позвольте быть вашим оруженосцем? ― **Сочту за честь,** милорд.

― Разрешите присоединиться к вам, благородный дон? ― **Сочту за честь**, благородный дон.  [Аркадий Стругацкий, Борис Стругацкий. Трудно быть богом (1963)]

**Так говорят сейчас:**

Больше того, после вашего ответа **я почту за честь** выпить с вами. [Виктор Пелевин. Чапаев и пустота (1996)]

Answer (score 2):

Если Вы ищете ссылку на какой-то источник, то нужно искать во фразеологических словарях. Я посмотрел несколько, но нашёл только в одном: Фразеологический словарь русского языка, Федосов И.В., Лапицкий А.Н.:

> **Считать (или ставить) за честь** что — признавать почетным для себя

То же сказано в фундаментальном 4-томном словаре русского языка. См. [здесь](https://kartaslov.ru/%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0/%D1%81%D1%87%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C%20(%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%B8%20%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%8C%20%D0%B8%20%D1%82.%20%D0%BF.)%20%D0%B7%D0%B0%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C) и дальше по ссылке на электронную версию оригинала.

Answer (score 1):

Выражение относится к редкоупотребимым (не в последнюю очередь по причине оттенков смысла, не всегда и не везде сохранившихся в современном российском обществе).

Примерный смысл таков: "буду чувствовать, что меня уважают, считая равным себе, когда/если..." (далее, как правило, следует описание каких-либо действий в пользу адресата или адресатов высказывания, например):

> Сочту за честь помочь Вам. = Буду чувствовать, что Вы меня уважаете,
>   считая равным себе, когда примете мою помощь.
>
> Сочту за честь принять участие. = Буду чувствовать, что меня уважают,
>   считая равным себе, когда смогу принять участие.
>
> Сочту за честь написать скрипт. = Буду чувствовать, что меня уважают,
>   считая равным себе, когда напишу скрипт [для этого проекта].
>
> Сочту за честь пригласить Вас. = Буду чувствовать, что Вы меня
>   уважаете, считая равным себе, если примете моё приглашение.
>
> Публикацию в вашем издательстве сочту за честь. = Буду чувствовать,
>   что меня уважают, считая равным другим авторам, когда моя работа будет
>   опубликована в вашем издательстве.

Comment: Скажите, пожалуйста, из какого источника ваш ответ (или это ваше мнение)?

Comment: Я владею русским языком. зарабатываю лингвистикой и литературой. Ваш вопрос несколько оскорбителен для меня, поскольку адекватный критерий качества ответа - его применимость, а не источник.

Comment: Извините, я не это имел в виду. Я просто хотел узнать, если материал, словари, где об этом можно прочитать.  И можно тогда в дополнение спросить, "сочту за честь" и "это честь для меня" синонимичные выражения? Например, "Сочту за честь помочь вам" и "это честь для меня - помочь вам"?

Comment: Мне такие словари (по оборотам и выражениям "золотого" и "серебряного" веков) не встречались. Можно попробовать посмотреть в корпусах. Разница, как я понимаю, в том, что "сочту за честь" и "это честь для меня" в равной степени могут использоваться как ответы, а "это честь для меня" в начале распространенного высказывания, в отличие от "это честь для меня" звучит не очень естественно, больше похоже на кальку с французского. Соответственно, "это честь" - более редкое выражение, что подтверждается материалами корпуса.

Comment: "Это честь для меня" встречается реже в корпусе: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%FD%F2%EE+%F7%E5%F1%F2%FC+%E4%EB%FF+%EC%E5%ED%FF

Comment: "Сочту за честь" тоже не выглядит особо частоупотребимым: http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%F1%EE%F7%F2%F3+%E7%E0+%F7%E5%F1%F2%FC

Answer (score -1):

Посчитаю (= *сочту*) долгом честно (= *без корысти*) помочь.